# Determine the cluster for a new document with Scikit

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

I have implemented the k-means algorithm in scikit. Therefore, I have clustered the historical documents. Now, for a new document I want to determine the cluster.
How can I determine the cluster for the new document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you built your classifier using:

```
km = KMeans()
km.fit(X)
```

If you have `X_new_sample` with the same vector format as `X`, you can use `predict()` to identify which cluster each row in `X_new_sample` belongs to.

```
km.predict(X_new_sample)
```